# Downloading a Torrent file and save it in user defined directory using urllib2?

Tags: python, django

How to download a torrent file and save it in a user defined directory using urllib 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing the work yourself using urllib2.urlopen, I recommend using urllib.urlretrieve as that will do the work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

That is not so important that you want download torrent file.
You can download and save file of any type this way:

```
import urllib2
with open("mytorrent", "w") as f:
  f.write(urllib2.urlopen('http://megatorrent.com/torrent-url').read())
```

File from `http://megatorrent.com/torrent-url` will be saved in the current directory as `mytorrent`.

When you want to save the file in other directory you do something like:

```
import urllib2
with open(os.path.join(torrents_die_path, "mytorrent"), "w") as f :
  f.write(urllib2.urlopen('http://megatorrent.com/torrent-url').read())
```

Comment: The Python docs recommend against using `file()` to open a file - using `open()` with the `with` statement is the best way. In fact, it is removed in 3.x